# Making rule and Query in SWRL Tab

Tags: java, protege

I'm study about data structuring by protege and I have some errors in my ontology file. In my case, i just want to make some specific code in swrl tab with this conditions:

1. Class: peter, james, sindy
2. Object Property: Result
3. Instance: a
4. if 3 kind of classes input in the DL Query, the reult have to reflect Instance "a"

and the code : peter(?x) ^ james(?x) ^ sindy(?x) -> Result(?x, a)
when i making the code, the code change automatically > autogen0:peter(?x) ^ autogen0:james(?x) ^ autogen0:sindy(?x) -> autogen0:Result(?x, autogen0:a)

the "run drool" is not the problem but still not came out the result that i mentioned.

the class structure is followed:
owl:thing

- person

  - peter
  - sindy
  - james

instance: a(no type which connect any other classes)

object Property: Result

and there are no relationship with object. i just want to make the specific relationship with swrl code: "james and peter and sindy" > a

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.